# ISC DHCP Server "Dynamic and static leases present"

Tags: debian, dhcp, dhcp-server, isc-dhcp

i have a problem similar to [Fixed and dynamic IPs in ISC DHPD lead to double lease](https://serverfault.com/questions/376713/fixed-and-dynamic-ips-in-isc-dhpd-lead-to-double-lease)

In my DHCP-Log I often receive warnings like

```
Jan 21 10:20:56 dc2 dhcpd: Dynamic and static leases present for 192.168.1.107.
Jan 21 10:20:56 dc2 dhcpd: Remove host declaration Ares or remove 192.168.1.107
Jan 21 10:20:56 dc2 dhcpd: from the dynamic address pool for 192.168.1.0/24
Jan 21 10:20:56 dc2 dhcpd: DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.1.107 from 00:24:d7:de:60:50 via eth0
Jan 21 10:20:56 dc2 dhcpd: DHCPACK on 192.168.1.107 to 00:24:d7:de:60:50 via eth0
```

I am a bit confused and cannot imagine, why this errors appear?
Yesterday I also had the problem, that one of my computers did't got the IP from the static entry. Instead he got an IP of the dynamic pool.

This is my dhcpd.conf

```
subnet 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {

   option domain-name-servers 192.168.1.8;
   option domain-name "x";
   ddns-domainname "x";
   ddns-rev-domainname "in-addr.arpa.";
   option routers 192.168.1.2;
   option broadcast-address 192.168.1.255;
   option domain-search "x";
   option ntp-servers 192.168.1.8;
   option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
   option netbios-name-servers 192.168.1.205; #192.168.1.205;

   # Einige Einstellungen fuer WPAD Probleme
   option wpad "\n";
   # Bekannte Geraete
   pool {
        range 192.168.1.1 192.168.1.169;
        deny unknown-clients;
        }
   # Unbekannte Geraete
   pool {
        range 192.168.1.170 192.168.1.199;
        allow unknown-clients;
        }
   # Peripherie
   pool {
        range 192.168.1.200 192.168.1.240;
        deny unknown-clients;
        }
#       default-lease-time 600;
#       max-lease-time 7200;
}
#

# Reserveriungen...
include "/etc/dhcp/reservations.conf";
```

My intention was that only 192.168.1.170 - 199 is free for the dynamic area. Is the configuration wrong?

Cheers,
Lukas

Answer (score 5):

The error says it all, you have both static and dynamic lease present for the same ip address range.

In the following you have defined a dynamic lease:

```
# Bekannte Geraete
   pool {
        range 192.168.1.1 192.168.1.169;
        deny unknown-clients;
        }
```

Therefore you shouldn't configure static lease from this range anymore. I guess you have static lease configured from that same range here:

```
"/etc/dhcp/reservations.conf"
```

To resolve this, change the dynamic pool (Bekannte Geraete) as below or remove it, if you want to reserve it just for static lease only.

```
# Bekannte Geraete
       pool {
            range 192.168.1.1 192.168.1.169;
            deny all clients;
            }
```

Comment: You were right. Than it was apparently the similar solution as posted in the other question.
I just mixed up the function of "deny unknow-clients" and "deny all clients".
Thanks for clarifying this.